# Firestore ID token from user signin fails to authenticate in REST API calls

Tags: firebase, api, rest, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have some data that I have created in my Firestore. I am trying to access them using the REST API. But I am getting an authentication error. I am doing the following:

According to the Cloud Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization), I can

> "Generate a Firebase ID token using the Firebase Authentication REST
> API."

To get the `idToken` I am signing in a valid user in the following way:

```js
const API_KEY = 'my API key'
const URL_GET_TOKEN_BY_SIGN_IN = `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=${API_KEY}`;

const getTokensBySigningIn = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const res = await fetch(URL_GET_TOKEN_BY_SIGN_IN, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: `registered_user_email@somedomain.com`,
          password: "valid_password",
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

      const resData = await res.json().catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
      resolve(resData);
    });
  };
```

The returned promise resolves with an object of the form:

```js
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": "ZgnICJLhiJM5... some local id",
  "email": "registered_user_email@somedomain.com",
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N... a 985 char long token",
  "registered": true,
  "refreshToken": "AGEhc0Dq9fodOAAs_on5A... a 298 char long token",
  "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

So far so good. Now I take the `idToken` from the response and try to use it in the request headers (as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authenticating_with_an_access_token) says):

```js
  const getDocsFromFirestore = async () => {
    const responseSignin = await getTokensBySigningIn();
    const URL_GET_FIRESTORE_DATABASES = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/documents`;
    const response = await fetch(URL_GET_FIRESTORE_DATABASES, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${responseSignin.idToken}`,
      },
    });
    const responseFirestoreDB = await response.json();
    console.log(responseFirestoreDB);
  };
```

But now, if I call the `getDocsFromFireStore()` function, I get the following error:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Any help?

**Note that**, I have set the requirements of auth in the Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of request and response tab from chrome dev tools, the network tab??

Comment: Sure! Request Screenshot: https://ibb.co/L9GBXbw , and Response screen shot: https://ibb.co/NTd4tKh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying the database that you are looking into. Compare your API request URL with the one in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls):

```
/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Try changing your request URL to:

```js
const URL_GET_FIRESTORE_DATABASES = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents`;
```

That being said, there's no such endpoint. Are you trying to list documents of a specific collection? Then try specifying the collection name:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/users;
                                                                               ^^^^^
```

You can find more about REST API endpoints in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/#rest-resource:-v1beta1.projects.databases.documents).

Comment: Thanks! Adding the `/(default)/` part and the collection name at the end solved the problem. So, it was not really a problem in the authentication token! Misleading error message from firestore.